# How to get data from a db table in yii2

Tags: database, yii2

Is there a global way to get any data from the db table, as I could not find anything that did work(new to Yii2, and working on a already build yii2 application).

Working in a controller with the following code:(not working)

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM category_translation')->queryAll();
return $results;
```

This will return nothing but only an error.

Comment: What error? Yii2 have `Yii::$app->db` not Yii1 `Yii::app()->db`;

Comment: What do you mean by `global way`? You can use models almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code according to Yii2 standards

```
$results = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM category_translation')->queryAll();
```

return $results;